# hive TBLPROPERTIES equivalent to parquet files in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, parquet, delta-lake

I'm converting hql scripts to pyspark.
**HQL code** : `show tblproperties tblName ('transient_lastDdlTime')`
I want "transient_lastDdlTime" property equivalent for parquet files. I know there is a way for delta tabes using delta lake APIs, but is there a way for parquet files?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any such metadata in parquet files which will be equivalent of transient_lastDdlTime you can check the same by writing some parquet files and reading its metadata using below code

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
pq.read_metadata('<file_path>')
```

As you see there is no external metadata created like delta tables and parquet metadata only has some basic row and column information.

you will need to implement your own code for capturing timestamp of changes